# Lawnchair-0.6.1 js: Data not persisting between closing and reopening of browser

Tags: javascript, lawnchair

I am using Firefox version 32.0 and Chrome version 36.0. I want to use Lawnchair for a client side, **persistent** json data store. I created an HTML to try it out, as follows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>my osim app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="visit-times"/>
    <script src="http://brian.io/lawnchair/downloads/lawnchair-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var store = new Lawnchair({ name: 'testing' }, function (store) {

            store.get('counter', function (cnt) {
                if (!cnt) {
                    cnt = { key: 'counter', val: 1 }
                }
                else {
                    cnt.val++;
                }

                store.save(cnt);

                document.getElementById("visit-times").textContent = "You visited this page " + cnt.val + " times.";
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am opening this HTML file (located on IIS development server) in both of the browsers, it shows count 1 and increases it when refreshed. But, on closing and reopening of the browser, it starts the counter from 1 again.

I want to use this data, not only in the file which created it, but also in other files hosted on same domain / subdomain.

Can anybody please tell me how can I have a persistent client side data store?

Comment: Did you check your browser for errors?  No experience with the library but a quick look at the docs says its should be `var store = lawnchair({ name: 'testing' }, ...`

Comment: No errors. Its working just fine, but clearing all data between closing and reopening, which should not happen.